# Microsoft Graph API returning 404 when I try to access "me/licenseDetails"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, ms-office

I have Office365 subscriptions for two users. One has Office365 enterprise and the other has Office365 home edition. I get a 200 response and license information when I hit the `me/licenseDetails` endpoint using the enterprise user, but I get a 404 when I use the home user. Am I only able to access license information for enterprise users? I don't see this mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-licensedetails?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). I just need to verify the user has a valid Office license.